# Why does read-line not return after hitting ENTER (seems like a hang) using lein run, but works with lein repl?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

The problem at hand is that when I run my program with `lein run` it gets to the `(read-line)` part and I can't get out of it, meaning: read-line never returns.

Here is the relevant code:

```
(def command (atom ""))

(defn print-prompt []
  (print "prompt> ")
  (flush)
)

(defn ask-for-input []
    (print-prompt)
    (let [x (str (read-line))]
      (println (str "User input: " x))
      (reset! command x)
    )
)
```

I never see the "User input: " string on screen.
The strange part is, if I run `lein repl` and call `(ask-for-input)` then it works correctly :S

Comment: What's command? Would you consider editing your original post and putting that in? I'm trying to build your code and have a look at it. I think I know what it is, but it would be nice to see it. Thanks.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus There, I added the missing line.

Comment: At the lein repl, how do you call this? I just entered (ask-for-input). Admittedly, I have my area set up like a project. I'll post the project and src header in my answer as an edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try **lein trampoline run**, it works.

The following is from leiningen FAQ:

> Q: I don't have access to stdin inside my project.
>
> A: This is a limitation of the JVM's process-handling methods; none of them expose stdin correctly. This means that functions like read-line will not work as expected in most contexts, though the repl task necessarily includes a workaround. You can also use the trampoline task to launch your project's JVM after Leiningen's has exited rather than launching it as a subprocess.

Comment: Yes it does! Now would you care to explain why is that? :)

Comment: My guess is lein trampoline run works, because the data is being flushed out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your source code, but omitted the flush. It worked without a problem. What version of Clojure are you using? I tried the following code with Clojure 1.3.

```
(def command (atom 0))

(defn print-prompt []
  (print "prompt> ")
)

(defn ask-for-input 
    []
    (print-prompt)
    (let [x (str (read-line))]
      (println (str "User input: " x))
      (reset! command x)
    ))
```

Edit:
I altered one of your functions that I copied and tested with, and it works now with standalone and lein run. You had (flush) in your original example.

```
(defn print-prompt []
  (print "prompt> ")
  (flush)
)
```

From what I can garner, println causes a flush, print doesn't, and you need a flush after print.

I am adding this information in case it might be of help. I have a Clojure project called repl-test. Here is my repl-test project's core.clj file header. Your source, already posted, is in this file with some other functions, not related to your post.

```
(ns repl-test.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:use clojure.contrib.command-line)
  (:require [clojure.contrib.string :as cstr])
  (:require [clojure.contrib.trace :as ctr])
  (:require [clojure.string :as sstr])
  (:use clojure-csv.core))
```

And here is the project.clj file:

```
(defproject repl-test "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "TODO: add summary of your project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.2.4"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]
                 [clj-http "0.1.3"]]
   :aot [repl-test.core]
   :main repl-test.core)
```

Comment: I was using 1.3 and switched to 1.4 to see if that would help, but it didn't.

Comment: Add my project and core.clj headers.

Comment: Same deal, remember that on Repl it works, if I do `lein repl` and then call `(-main)` the program works correctly, but if I run it with `lein run` the read-line never returns. BTW my cored IS working correctly with the trampoline option.. do you happen to know why?

Comment: If you look at my post, you'll see that the `(flush)` is there, you removed it in your example, but it was there all along.

Comment: Got it. I put flush back, and it does work for me running as an uberjar or lein run.