# Handling stdin Clojure

Tags: clojure, stdin

The below doesn't seem to work, but I'm not quite sure why. All move-board does is take in a 2D array and return a 2D array, rest of the code is all there.  Basically I'm trying to accomplish something like the following python:

```
While True:
  do stuff
  if gameover:
    print("Game Over!")
    break
```

Clojure that isn't working (prints board once, asks for input, then hangs)

```
(defn game-loop [board]
  (loop [b board]
    (if (game-over? b) "Game Over!"
        (do (print-board b)
            (recur (move-board (read-line) b))))))
```

Comment: You could try binding (let) the result of `read-line` separately and printing that out to see whether `read-line` returns. Another place to check would be your `game-over?` function; is it recurring infinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would need to see what your other functions are doing.  I
fabricated them minimally to what seems likely, and reindented to make
the if-branch clearer.  Your `loop` also was unnecessary.

```
(defn game-over? [b] false)
(defn print-board [b] (println b))
(defn move-board [ln b] (println "moving board:" ln))

(defn game-loop [b]
  (if (game-over? b)
    "Game Over!"
    (do (print-board b)
        (recur (move-board (read-line) b)))))

(game-loop :bored)
```

With those top three functions, your loop behaves as expected:
prompting for a single line, infinitely.  Well, at least the first
time, but then your "hang" issue is reproduced.

This is likely being caused by [this issue with the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883188/why-does-read-line-not-return-after-hitting-enter-seems-like-a-hang-using-lein).  Also [discussed here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/kYNWcfajHhY).

Comment: I excluded move-board because it calls many other functions, I would have to post most of the program.  I can assure you it works without issue though. What you assumed is basically fine, the only difference is that eventually the board will be at a terminal state and stop the recursion.  printboard just maps print to each row.

Comment: So - this was because I was running it in emacs/cider. When I do lein run (didn't have to trampline run), it works.  Guess there was no problem after all, but I'll mark this correct for your effort :)